# Flutter run -v stuck at downloading jar file ( kotlin-compiler-embeddable_1.6.10 )

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, gradle

[The jar file that is not downloading no matter what](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUIJQ.png), its been a whole day and I'm stuck with it,

- Restarting the computer or  ( vs code , Android studio)
- Manually downloading the file and placing it there (it was in jar format, but vs code looks for bin)
- Changing internet connection
- Deleting Cache
- Stuff stuff

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you try

1. flutter clean
2. flutter upgrade

if issue persist, perhaps you can simply delete the SDK and re-download afresh. It might be due to corrupt files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with these steps:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

The only solution that worked was to wait for a few hours.